# Why does this relay not turn on but it is connected to 12V?

Tags: relay, driver

I am looking at a driver for my relay, but in the applications page I am confused as to how the 12V battery at the high side does not already turn on the relay?

Attached is the picture from the datasheet of NUD3124. [image]

Comment: Why would you expect the relay to be turned on without the negative connection (which is broken by the transistor)?

Comment: Do you see the transistor on the way?

Comment: Ahhh! I see that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both sides of the coil will be at +12 with the pin (1) low. So no current (to speak of) through the coil and the relay does not pull in.

When the input on pin (1) is high, the transistor turns on and then voltage is +12 on one side of the coil and about 0V on the other so the relay pulls in.

Immediately when (1) goes low after being high, the voltage on the drain of the transistor will shoot up to about +35V before falling back to +12 in a few milliseconds (depending on the relay). That is the Zener clamping function .